# distinct edges and vertices (graph theory)

Tags: graph-theory

I want to ask about the relationship between distinct vertices and distinct edges.

I was able to come up with an explanation for
"distinct vertices" $\Rightarrow$ "distinct edges".

An edge is considered the same if it has the same endpoints (am I allowed to take this as self-evident?).
Therefore, if all vertices are distinct in a walk, no vertex appears twice, so every edge is distinct.

Is this correct? Also, is the converse true/can I make a counterexample?

Comment: The converse is certainly false. You can have a walk with distinct edges visiting any given vertex many times, if you have enough distinct edges meeting at that vertex.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct, and multigraphs would need a stronger definition.